# Mat-Tab Background Color affecting the child tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I'm using Angular 8 and [Angular Material Tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)

I create a Tab within a Tab, my code looks something like this :

```
<mat-tab-group [backgroundColor]="primary">
    <mat-tab label="All Taxonomy">
        <div>
              <app-main-stats></app-main-stats> //<-- this component will contain another tab
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

> On **main-stats.component.html**

```
 <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Basic">
            <div>
                  Tab content
            </div>
          </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

I just want to coloring the Level 1 tab. But the Tab child affected too, is that any possible way to solve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just specify the coloring on CSS.

.html:

```
<mat-tab-group id="parent">
    <mat-tab label="All Taxonomy">
        <div>
      Child:
            <mat-tab-group>
                <mat-tab label="Basic">
                    <div>
                        Tab content
                    </div>
                </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

.css:

```
::ng-deep #parent > mat-tab-header {
  background-color:#673ab7;
}
::ng-deep #parent > mat-tab-header > .mat-tab-label-container > .mat-tab-list > .mat-tab-labels > .mat-tab-label {
  color: #fff;
}
::ng-deep #parent > mat-tab-header > .mat-tab-label-container > .mat-tab-list > mat-ink-bar {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```